# Aligning ion-content with ion-footer in different browsers

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that includes an ion-content and ion-footer component. The ion-content has enough content to cause a scrollbar to appear.

When I scroll, I want the content of the ion-content to align with the ion-footer. The problem is that in Chrome desktop, the scrollbar adds an extra 16px, while on Chrome mobile and Firefox it does not add anything.

Is there a standard way to ensure the content aligns across different browsers? Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" #content (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)" [scrollEvents]="true">
  <div class="main-content">
   <!-- scrollbar cause right padding -->
   <element/>
  </div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer class="ion-no-border ">
  <ion-toolbar  class="main-content ">
    <!--whitout padding -->
    <element/>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```